# usar string en clausula IN para comparar con un campo int

Tags: mysql, sql

Me gustaria saber como puedo comparar un campo(bigint) con un string como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
select * from t left join d on t.id = d.t_id where t.posiciones in (d.posiciones)
```

- t.posiciones (bigint)
- siendo d.posiciones este string: 5950,5951,5952,5960,5961,5962,5963,5964,5965,5966,5967,5968,5969,5970,5971,5972,5973,5974,5975,5976,5977,5978,5979,5980,5981,5982,5983

Answer (score 1):

usando esta funcion de mysql se puede realizar el query

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, comma_delimited_string)
```

Comment: te falta añadir antes del where : ``select * from t left join d on t.id = d.t_id``